# How to reduce search result when you have more than one word?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i need to write a search engine. And i had occurred some prbolems with it.

so for now my query looks like this.

```
SELECT * FROM umowy WHERE keywords LIKE ('%propanek%' OR '%seba%')
```

And i making this, with this example of code. (two words for now)

```
$szukaj = $_POST['szukaj'];
$szukaj_trim = trim($szukaj);
$szukaj_array = explode(" ",$szukaj_trim);
$szukaj_length = count($szukaj_array);

if ($szukaj_length === 1 ) {
    $constr = "('%${szukaj_array[0]}%')";
}
else{
    for($i = 0; $i <= $szukaj_length; $i++){

        if($i == 0){
            $constr = $constr."('%${szukaj_array[${i}]}%'";
        }
        if($i > 0 && $i < ($szukaj_length-1)){
            $constr = $constr." OR '%${szukaj_array[${i}]}%'";
        }
        if ($i == ($szukaj_length-1)) {
            $constr = $constr." OR '%${szukaj_array[${i}]}%')";
        }
    }
}

$query="SELECT * FROM umowy WHERE keywords LIKE $constr";
```

Is there way to reduce a result output by adding more words in search input?
Now it's working like "more words, more content to show". But i need something opposite, more words, the more accurate result is.

(sorry for my not perfect english)

Comment: Hint:  MySQL full text indexes.  You can just google that.

Comment: use `AND` instead of `OR`. Also, what you have is not a valid/intelligible sql condition; you cannot `LIKE` a list, you would need to do  `x LIKE '%blah%' OR x LIKE '%bleh%'`

Comment: @up this is what i was looking for, thanks!